# Angular UI Bootstrap pagination - show first 12 records in ng-repat on inital page load

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dzq85QFR2bvej3ShAfEs?p=preview) for a working example of my issue.

Pagination is working when I click on a pagination page number but does not initially load the data for the first page (first set of records). The moment you click on a number it works fine.

Please note: the above plunker is just a demo for SO, my real project is more complex so I cant just get rid of the dataService etc.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'ui.bootstrap.pagination']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.data = [];

  dataService.getAll()
            .then(function (response) {
                // Success
                $scope.data = response.data;
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.data.length;
            }, function (data, status, header, config) {
                // Failure
            });

  $scope.itemsPerPage = 12;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;

  $scope.pageCount = function () {
    return Math.ceil($scope.data/ $scope.itemsPerPage);
  };

  $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function () {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
    end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

    $scope.filtered = $scope.data.slice(begin, end);
  });

});
```

//DataService

```
(function() {

"use strict";

angular.module("plunker").factory("dataService", dataService);

function dataService($http) {

     return {
        getAll: getAll
     }

     function getAll() {

        return $http.get("http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd");
    }
}

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/2yHEukhKZcFplmJaFv0P

Added a function `updateView()`

and this function is called once the data is loaded at first and in your watch